# JMeter: Sending Ajax requests

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have a scenario which looks like:

```
  1. Transaction Controller-1
  2. Transaction Controller-2
  3. Transaction Controller-3
  4. Transaction Controller-4
  5. Transaction Controller-5
```

Irrespective of the Transaction Controller or Wait Time being executed, an ajax request is to be sent every 5 secs.

How do I handle this? Please help.

Thanks for your support.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter:

1. Executes [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down
2. Executes next Sampler as soon as it gets response from the current one (or faces connect/response timeout)

So if you want to run a request each 5 seconds no matter what is going on you should add it to another [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and use a [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) or [Flow Control Action Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action). If you need to pass some data (cookies, token, whatever) you can [convert it into JMeter Properties or use Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-variables)

[image]